# Passing data through React Router to components

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux

I'm struggling to do anything with react/redux.

One of my last challenges was to pass some data from Child Component to Parent Component. I couldn't get the child `props` by calling parentComponent.props.children.props (I also tried converting children to Array with React.Children.toArray) and then I found a solution for my specific problem reading some data that comes with React Router.

I managed to find out the child component by calling `this.props.location.pathname` in Parent Component.

I have a Routing structure as following

```
<Router history={history}>
      <Route path="/main" component={Main}>
        <Route path="something" component={Something} />   
      </Route>
</Router>
```

I wonder if it is possible to pass some data to Main in this declaration. Something like:

```
<Route path="something" component={Something} data={foo: 'myData'} />
```

And get `foo` in the `Main.render`

Is there something close to this?

Answer (score 2):

You could pass 'myData' as a query parameter.  This is my personal preference for passing props to a component using React Router.  Then when you browse to `/main/something?foo=myData`, you can access `foo` from `this.props.location.query.foo`.

Answer (score 1):

Any props you pass to the route definition is accessible under the route node in the props. In your Something component, should be able to get the data prop with `this.props.route.data`

Comment: there is no `this.props.route.data` for me.
I can see what I'm passing as a props in `this.props.route.childRoutes[#]['myPropsName']`